# Intuitive way of understanding quadratic magnetoresistance

Tags: condensed-matter, electrical-resistance

Many papers that I have read regarding magnetoresistance in metals say that magnetoresistance should evolve quadratically with field. Apart from referring me to the Boltzmann transport equation, is there an intuitive way to understand why this is so? Why can't it be linear? (P.s. I know some materials have linear MR, I just want to know why most metals have B^2 dependence of magnetoresistance.)

I saw somewhere that it could be due to time-reversal symmetry, but I haven't been able to draw the link.